# jQuery autopopulate select drop down from JSON issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, coldfusion, each

I have an issue regarding to auto populating a select dropdown from jQuery/JSON data which is return from a ColdFusion CFC, the code is below:

```
$(function(){
$("#licences-add").dialog({autoOpen:false,modal:true,title:'Add Licences',height:250,width:380});
```

});

```
function openAddLicence(intInstanceID,szName,szDatasourceName){
$.getJSON('/ASPAdmin/billing/handler.cfc?method=ListLicenceTypes&queryformat=column',{szInstanceDatasource:szDatasourceName}, 
    function(data){   
        $.each(data,function(){
            $('<option></option>').val(data.DATA.UUIDLICENCETYPE).text(data.DATA.SZLICENCETYPE).appendTo('#uuidLicenceType');
        });
    });
$("#intInstanceID").attr('value', intInstanceID);
$('span#szInstanceName').text(szName);
$("#licences-add").dialog('open');};
```

The json returned is:

```
{"ROWCOUNT":1,"COLUMNS":["UUIDLICENCETYPE","SZLICENCETYPE"],"DATA":{"UUIDLICENCETYPE":["480CE560-BCD3-C7AC-AF50B3C71BBCC473"],"SZLICENCETYPE":["Standard"]}}
```

However i get the following error:

> $("").val(this.UUIDLICENCETYPE).text is not a function

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<tr>
<td><label for="uuidLicenceType" title="Select the licence type (required).">Licence Type</label> <span class="req">*</span></td>
<td>
    <select name="uuidLicenceType" id="uuidLicenceType" class="bmSelect">
        <option value=""></option>
    </select>
</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the JSON you're returning isn't an array, you just need this:

```
function(data){
  var select = $('#uuidLicenceType');
  $('<option />', {
    val: data.DATA.UUIDLICENCETYPE,
    text: data.DATA.SZLICENCETYPE[0]
  }).appendTo(select);
}
```

The `$.each()` the current code calls is looping over the oject's properties...to see this just put `alert(this)` in the loop, so inside the loop it's seeing `1`, the column array, and the data object at the end.  [You can see this in a demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ahdwh/).

Since you just want to access properties on a single object, use the dot notation above to get at them directly.  If you change the format and get an array of these, then wrap what I have above in a `$.each()` and replace `data` with `this` inside that loop.

**Updated for comments**: Your `SZLICENCETYPE` is being returned as an array: `"SZLICENCETYPE":["Standard"]`, so you need to fetch the first element from it using `[0]`.

Comment: Not getting an error for those changes so i guess its working, however it doesnt seems to be appending to the select...

And i'm getting this error from the jquery.min.js file:
G is undefined
[Break on this error] (function(){var l=this,g,y=l.jQuery,p=...ch(function(){o.dequeue(this,E)})}});

Comment: @Jonathon - Can you post the html section containing your `<select>` ?

Comment: Added the HTML to the question description, and the updated jquery...
The form is in a hidden div which gets opened by a jquery ui dialog box if that makes any difference?

Comment: @Jonathon - Updated the answer, the important change is `SZLICENCETYPE` needs to be `SZLICENCETYPE[0]` when assigning the text to the option.  Also, it looks like your still using an each, make sure not to unless you're now returning an array of these items :)